# Convert an area to meters² in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, convert, geography

I have this query :

```
SELECT ST_AREA(geom::geography) FROM region
```

The (geom) contains polygons from a shapefile imported into PostGIS with shp2pgsql.
I've appended ::geography, else the result of the function was displayed in degrees.
Now, I have this kind of answer :

```
544163926.22948
```

How can I know in which units it is displayed ? square/meters ? square/foot ?
I want it to be displayed in square/meters (m²) ou square/kilometers (km²)

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [PostGIS Docs for ST_Area()](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Area.html) say:

> For "geography" area is in square meters.